# The position: fixed is not working over option tag in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I want to have a header in select tag with fixed positioning but setting the position value to fixed in IE browser is not working for the option tag

```html
<select multiple style="height:130px">
  <option value="volvo" style="position:fixed">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will be respected by IE...  You can't style option tags. Use a `<select>` replacement like Select2.

Comment: uhm ... that's not specific to IE - firefox also won't keep that option fixed in place - which would look odd when scrolling a page anyway! It seems Chrome will do it, it looks awful and also stays in place when the page scrolls - positioning an option "fixed" would appear to be unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `<optgroup>` tag? Maybe this is can help you determine what you're looking for in this jsfiddle. But I don't think adding a `style` attribute to an `option` tag will work for all browsers nor will it look correct. I think `<optgroup>` might be the closest you will get to achieve something of the sort.

https://jsfiddle.net/9pudbj0z/